# Why does the text inside an element budge when I get the dropshadow effect by hovering the mouse over it?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, dropshadow

I have a custom UserControl, a grid containing a single large button with a few elements inside of it. I added a dropshadow effect when the mouse is over it, it all works but the text inside the button either slightly stretch vertically or get a vertical movement, it's hard to tell, some may say it gets blurry. It's very noticeable and distracting, specially when quickly getting the mouse over it on an and off in succession.

I wonder what is causing it and how to fix it.

I am going to attach a couple of pictures, they might not do the issue justice.
[without dropshadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEh6B.png)
[with dropshadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkhrA.png)

I tried changing a few of the main grid attributes based on some posts here with blurry text and dropshadow, but to no effect - `UseLayoutRounding` and `SnapsToDevicePixels`. I thought the issue could be with the `Width` and `Height` somehow forcing the rendering into a restricted fixed size, but nothing worked.

I also tried `TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"` that helped a bit but did not completely fix the issue, the texts still move.

I put the content of the button in a border as some solutions suggested but then I couldn't click the button, and it didn't even help with the moving texts.

What else can be done?

Edit: Adding reproducing code for a button with a triggered dropshadow on mouse over.

```
<Button Background="White" Margin="20,20,0,0" Width="300" Height="200" >
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <TextBlock FontSize="12" FontWeight="Light" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    Text
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Effect">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DropShadowEffect Direction="270" ShadowDepth="3" BlurRadius="14" Opacity="0.2"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: Drop Shadow is a bitmap effect that applies to all content of the element you apply the effect to.

Comment: @Andy, I don't think it's the same effect  that I am experiencing, since the texts move the exact same way no matter the parameters of the dropshadow effect. Besides, as in the site you pointed I had the background property of the Button set to a fixed color, meaning it's a different problem I am having.

Comment: What is the minimum markup and code which reproduces your issue?

Comment: @Andy, I added to the post a snippet that reproduces the issue.

Comment: You're applying an effect to the container template. The textblock is inside that. Read that link I posted again. Because that is you problem.

Comment: @Andy, here's what I tried. I took the same code from the link you posted, and I checked the text while manually commenting the DropShadow effect in and out of the code while the app was running, I had the same shift/blur. This is not the same problem, it's something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found worked best visually was to create a Border underneath the bottom, as a sibling to the main button. Then I added MouseEnter and MouseLeave event handlers where I respectively add and remove the DropShadow effect from this extra Border. It works really well and causes no noticeable distortion to text or image on the original button.